# How to create a git executable file to go to a specific directory

Tags: git, shell

When I open the git Shell window, I have to do each day the same thing.
I start in location: `~/Desktop/Github`
Then I have to repeat these steps all the time. 
Is there a way to create a executable file to run these commands ?

```
cd y:
cd Websites
cd Projects
etc..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine gave the answer, but it was very simple, You just have to run GitHub (not the shell) and then to, tools -> options and then in the default storage directory you go to your default work path. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the usual way to do what you need is to [script your shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script).  Note that more advanced programming languages could be used instead of the shell.  For instance, if you have Git installed, changes are good you already have Perl and Tcl available at your disposal.

Comment: thanks, but I tried to make an .bat file with no succes.
what kind of file extension do I need to save the file to make it executable in git?

Comment: Git is not a runtime, so what do you mean by saying "executable in Git"? An update to your question with some example would be a good start.